# Issue: VLC player opens up separate windows for video and audio in Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: linux, vlc, ubuntu-20.04, snap

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and I installed [VLC player from snap store](https://snapcraft.io/vlc) (version: 3.0.16).

but when I open up a video file with VLC player, it opens up a window for the video and another window for the audio.

I have tried few solutions mentioned in [this website](https://superuser.com/questions/126525/vlc-shows-two-windows-for-one-video), but it did not work for me. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Also got this issue with the snap version 3.0.16. Removing `/home/<user-name>/snap/vlc/current/.config/vlc` worked for me, but I had to keep removing that file often because the issue would reappear.

The permanent solution for me was to get rid of the snap version via `sudo snap remove vlc`, and then install an apt version via `sudo apt-get install vlc`. At the time of writing, the new version I got from apt was 3.0.9.2 Vetinari.

Answer (score 3):

With Nvidia proprietary Graphic-Driver do this:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1384279

Change Video Output setting and also change Input/Codecs -> Hardware-accelerated decoding setting to: `VDPAU`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove and reinstall works for me.

sudo snap remove vlc

sudo apt-get install vlc

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this conversation](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/mj31d0/why_does_my_vlc_player_plays_videos_in_two/) I found a fix, but I will add some details to make things easier for you.

Follow these steps to fix the issue:

1. Open up the Files and go to the following directory.

```
/home/<user-name>/snap/vlc/current/.config/vlc
```

2. You will find a `.conf` file called `vlc-qt-interface.conf`.
3. Delete that file.
4. Then open up VLC again and try to play a video file. Hopefully you will fix the issue.

Note that you can use the terminal and delete this `.conf` file too.

Answer (score 0):

This fix works maybe one time, then the problem returns.

Tried deleting the same file in ~/.config/vlc/ but that also seems to fail after working one time.

Logging out and logging back in also clears the problem - ONE TIME.  Then it returns.

Where is it reloading this session?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).